# Using raw_input after using fileinput

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdin

I have a python script that can read it's data from stdin or from a file. In order to do this, I use [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) in the following manner:

```
for line in fileinput.input(args.path):
    read.parseLine(line)
```

Which works fine. However, after reading this file/input, I want to be able to ask the user for some additional input through stdin using read:

```
data = raw_input("Please enter your data for port {}: ".format(core.getPort()))
```

This does not work, since raw_input keeps on encountering an EOF.

```
Please enter your data for port 0: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "app_main.py", line 72, in run_toplevel
    File "/usr/local/bin/dvm", line 98, in <module>
    data = raw_input("Please enter your data for port {}: ".format(core.getPort()))
EOFError
```

I tried to resolve this by using`sys.stdin.seek(0)` But that returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "app_main.py", line 72, in run_toplevel
    File "/usr/local/bin/dvm", line 88, in <module>
    sys.stdin.seek(0)
IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek: '<fdopen>'
```

Is there any way to ask for user input after using fileinput?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileinput` doesn't do anything to `sys.stdin` other than read (it explicitly makes sure not to close `sys.stdin`).

But you cannot use `sys.stdin` both as file input *and* for `raw_input()`; either `sys.stdin` is attached to a pipe, *or* it is connected to the user terminal. It cannot be attached to both. And `fileinput` would read from `stdin` indefinitely unless an end-of-file was reached at some point.

In other words, you cannot use `raw_input` when `sys.stdin` is not attached to a terminal. You could use the [`os.isatty()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.isatty) to detect if a terminal is available:

```
if os.isatty(sys.stdin.fileno()):
    # we have a terminal, I can use `raw_input()`
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's impossible to change the destination of stdin at execution time?

Comment: @mathsaey: The *destination* is your script. You cannot change the source, no. That's all set up before Python is even run.

Comment: Alright, would it be possible to ask for user input in some other way if stdin is bound to a pipe?

Comment: Command-line switches perhaps? `stdin` is out, no pun intended.

Comment: In my case, I can pass the information requested by the raw_input through the command line, so I'll probably just go that route. Allow either input through stdin, or passing fileinput through stdin, but not both.

Regardless, thank you for your help, I'll accept this tomorrow if nobody came up with something.